# Error while executing in cmd prompt

Tags: java, swing

http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/java/visualization.jar

This file contains the advance data structures..

I got a complete source code using java decompiler and when i try to execute it from command prompt it is showing error...

Comment: why there is a tag `javascript`. If you think they both are same you are wrong.

Comment: show whats the error and how u r compiling and executing the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Java installed (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml), and you've downloaded the .jar file to your local system, the command to run it would be `java -jar /path/to/file.jar`.

But based on your statement "This file contains the advance data structures", it's possible the owner intended you to extract it as an archive.  See this article for instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html.